# Java Singleton.getInstance() returns null?

Tags: java, singleton, autoboxing

I have this singleton I'm trying to use, but getInstance can apparently return null:

```
class Singleton {
    public static final String K_LEVEL = "level";
    static Singleton instance = new Singleton();
    private int level;

    static Singleton getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }

    int getLevel() {
        return level;
    }

    void incrementLevel() {
        System.out.println("LEVEL INCREASED TO " + ++level);
    }

    void addToLevel(int x) {
        for(int i=0;i<x;i++)
            incrementLevel();
    }

}

class A {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Singleton s = Singleton.getInstance();
        Integer i = Integer.getInteger(Singleton.K_LEVEL);
        s.addToLevel(i);
    }
}
```

I heard implementing singletons in Java is very hard and prone to race conditions. Is my singleton pattern implemented wrong? I recently changed my code to look like this, and now getInstance returns null sometimes. Why?

```
$ java A -Dlevel=1
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at A.main(A.java:29)
```

Comment: What does `System.out.println(i);` right before `s.addToLevel(i);` print?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your Singleton. There are no concurrency problems because this is not multithreaded code.

You were thinking `s` was null, but it is really `i` that was null.

Since `addToLevel` takes an `int` as a parameter, the `Integer i` was autounboxed (implicitly converted from `Integer` to `int`), but since `i` was `null`, `NullPointerException` was thrown. Autounboxing throws `NullPointerException` when the value being coverted is `null`.

The reason `Integer.getInteger(Singleton.K_LEVEL)` returned `null` is because you did `java A -Dlevel=1` as opposed to `java -Dlevel=1 A`. The latter is the correct syntax.

Answer (score 3):

This is not about your singleton pattern which looks fine to me.  It is the `Integer.getInteger(Singleton.K_LEVEL);` method that is returning null.  I bet the `"level"` system property has not been set and is `null`.

> ```
> java A -Dlevel=1
> ```

You need to put the `-Dlevel=1` *before* the `A` class on the command-line. If you debug your code or print out the system property you will see that it is null.

```
java -Dlevel=1 A
```

You get a NPE when you try to pass the `null` into `addToLevel(int x)` and it tries to auto-unbox the `null` to be `int x`.

As an aside, if this class is used by multiple threads, you should consider using an `AtomicInteger` inside of your `Singleton` class which is reentrant.

Comment: No, I set it by doing this: `java A -Dlevel=1`

Comment: The `-D` has to be _before_ the `A` class @Dog.  I'd debug your code or print out the system property to verify it.

Comment: I agree. @Dog why don't you print i just before calling addToLevel to verify.

Comment: It sounds like you are going on from a speculation. Even if the getInteger was returning null, the cast should make it 0. I don't create other threads, but I don't know.. I thought perhaps the VM instantiates my singleton on another thread so that could by why I'm getting null for s?

Comment: Nope.  That's not how auto-boxing works.  You will and are getting a NPE because your system property is not set right @Dog.

Comment: see the below answer by sp00m. Looks like that's the reason. Its weird though.

Answer (score 2):

`java -Dlevel=1 A` should suit your needs.

From the [doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/tooldocs/windows/java.html), the syntax is `java [ options ] class [ argument ... ]`, and `-Dlevel=1` is considered as an option (see the [options](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/tooldocs/windows/java.html#options) section).

Answer (score 1):

`static Singleton instance = new Singleton();` should be final to prevent race condition.